# React Native bunch of buttons on top of background image

Tags: image, reactjs, native

I have a background image and I need to add bunch of oval buttons or images on in my case the "greenish" buttons on top of the background image, that I can click in each one of them  and call a function passing a parameter.  Please look on the screen shot and let me know how I can position every one of the buttons on top of the image and access them with a click (onPress). I guess the only way is using flex box but I couldn't figure out the style for it.

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just style all the green buttons on relatively to the image's boundaries with `position: absolute`. Percentage values for positioning should work, if your image scales properly on screen size change.

Comment: Thanks Denialos. It works. It just a lot of work because the number of buttons.